# Using a switch instead of a router, any issues?

Tags: internet, router

I am living in an on-campus apartment. These apartments have one ethernet port that we can connect a device to and we are not allowed to connect a router to it, we are to use campus wifi. If we are discovered as having a router, they will block the connection. My problem is that there is only one ethernet port in the whole apartment, and I have multiple devices I would like to connect to ethernet. I'm not trying to get wifi, so could I just connect the ethernet port to a switch (such as the TP-Link Gigabit switch)? I'm not very familiar with networks so if this would work, would it be slower (perhaps due to all devices receiving the same broadcast or something)?

Comment: Switch is much worse than a router for this matter. Router is not detectable (if properly configured. It is seen as a single network node, creating a sub-network not visible from outside. But switch is a "splitter", and everything connected to it is visible on the network. Anyway, the question is off topic, and the general advice would be *not to* try and mess with the rules.

Comment: Your network administrators are probably concerned about everyone having their own WiFi network and causing congestion. Why not ask them for a solution?

Comment: Eugene, I don't want to mess with the rules, I'm trying to find a solution within the rules. That is, I'm not trying to hide anything from the outside, I think the problem is we are not allowed to create wifi. I don't think there is a rule against changing one ethernet port into multiple.

Comment: Thanks KingDuken, I was hoping something like that would be the case. I will contact the network administrators to see if they will verify that just to be safe.

Comment: If so, you can use a regular wired router (if you can still find one these days..)

Comment: @SteveG They're probably concerned that a router could potentially (and unintentionally) create a backdoor into the network. It's the same reason why companies don't allow you to bring a router to work.

Comment: @KingDuken How can a router create a backdoor a PC cannot?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Just an easier way to discover a router than a single PC, in person at least. I'd trust Windows firewall over a router's firewall any day.

Comment: When you use the term "router" do you actually mean "WiFi router"? Are you aware that there is such a device as a router which does not create a WiFi network? Is your campus IT prohibiting *all routers* or *WiFi routers*?

Comment: @brhans very late response but yes I technically meant WiFi router, but they prohibit all routers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something you really need to discuss with the IT team as the answer depends entirely on their goals and network policies - and we can't answer that here.

- If they are trying to limit use of the network, installing your own switch would be very visible, as the MAC address of each device you plug in will be apparent. This could cause issues for the IT department if, for exame, there is a shortage of MAC addresses.
- They may be OK with you plugging in multie devices and have the limitation because they are are trying to maximise availability of WIFI, which is best done when they control all the channels. (By controlling WIFI they eliminate a tragedy-of-the-commons issue) If that is there goal they may not have a problem with you adding a switch - although you might ask for an exception to have your own router without WIFI in this case.
- The accepted answer is more-or-less correct except the last paragraph about sharing a PC - what he is describing is just "rolling your own" router, and from a technical POV IS a router - most routers are small computers running a variant of Linux to do exactly this.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to ask them. Without knowing the purpose of the rule, we can't know what they would like you to do and what they would object to. They might be okay with you using a switch. They might be okay with you using a wired router so long as there's no WiFi. They might be okay with you using a wireless router in client mode to create a wired network. They might have issues with everything you might want to do. We don't know.

Answer (score -2):

Connecting a switch will be detected even more easily than a router so I would say that if you're not allowed to use a router then for sure you should not use a switch.

A router can be configured to share one connection to more devices. A router can then "pretend" it is a single PC and share that connection with other devices.

A switch is much more "dumb" and cannot do that. If you connect multiple devices through a switch each device will ask for an IP address through that single connection. That can easily be detected (more easy than a router) at the other end of your ethernet connection.

Your way out might be to connect a PC to the ethernet port and share the internet connection of that PC. **Then the PC is the router so if that still fits the rules is up to you.**
 If the PC is a desktop without WiFi then buy a cheap WiFi USB stick to make it WiFi capable.

Comment: Not sure they won't consider a PC sharing the connection as a router.

Comment: "*Connecting a switch will be detected even more easily than a router so I would say that if you're not allowed to use a router then for sure you should not use a switch.*" That makes no sense at all. What does ease of detection have to do with whether or not the device is allowed? There's a rule against using routers. There's no rule, as far as we know, against using a switch. Also, a PC that's used as a router is a router.